# integration test of IBM worklight adapters with security test

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, rest-assured

I'm developing a POC for integration testing of IBM worklight adapters. In doing so I'm using [RESTAssured framework](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/). I have an adapter having security test applied to it. 
XML Snippet:

```
 <procedure name="getCatalog"
 securityTest="SingleStepAuthAdapter-securityTest" />
```

For authentication I have another adapter:

> `<procedure name="submitAuthentication" />`

In my test I'm calling SubmitAuthentication adapter and then I'm calling getCatalog adapter. This is returning me following error response:

> Runtime: The resource 'proc:SampleHttpAdapter.getCatalog' should only
>   be accessed when authenticated in realm 'SingleStepAuthRealm'.

Below is the test case i'm executing:

```
public void testGetCatalog() {

    Response response =   RestAssured.given().get(BASE_URL.concat("SampleHttpAdapter&
    procedure=submitAuthentication&parameters=[\"worklight\",\"worklight\"]"));
    String sessionid = response.getSessionId();
    Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie.Builder("JSESSIONID", sessionid).build();
    System.out.println("cookie value" + cookie1.getValue());
    RequestSpecification spec_two = new RequestSpecBuilder().addCookie(cookie1)
    .setSessionId(sessionid).build();
    Response catalog_response = RestAssured.given()
    .spec(spec_two)
    .get(BASE_URL.concat("SampleHttpAdapter&procedure=getCatalog&parameters=[]"));
    String catalog_json = catalog_response.asString();
    System.out.println(catalog_json);
}
```

As per the response it seems like the authentication is not persisting in my request of getCatalog. How can i do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your adapter procedures are written it is difficult to investigate the issue above. Can you please include the adapter procedures of submitAuthentication as well as getCatalog?

I can include to you a sample and tutorial Worklight proivides on adapter based authentication that will describe in great detail how the authentication process works. You can even use this project as a basis, since it accomplishes single step adapter authentication. Use the mechanisms it provides with authentication and add in your getCatalog method for testing.

Adapter Based Authentication Presentation:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_03_Adapter_based_authentication.pdf

Adapter Based Authentication Project:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/AdapterBasedAuthenticationProject.zip